# UISegmentedControl: no events fire when used in UIToolbar

Tags: c#, cocoa-touch, events, xamarin.ios, uisegmentedcontrol

Monotouch 4.2 beta.

I'm adding a `UISegmentedControl` to a `UIToolbar`.
The problem is that none of the events fire when switching segments. What am I missing here?

```
this.oBookmarkSwitch = new UISegmentedControl(new UIImage[] { UIImage.FromFile("./images/index.png"), UIImage.FromFile("./images/bookmark_grey.png") });
this.oBookmarkSwitch.TouchUpInside += delegate {
Console.WriteLine("TOUCHY - never fires");
};
this.oBookmarkSwitch.ValueChanged += delegate {
Console.WriteLine("CHANGE - only fires once when the control is created");
};
this.oBookmarkSwitch.Frame = new RectangleF(0, 0, 100, 30);
this.oBookmarkSwitch.ControlStyle = UISegmentedControlStyle.Bar;
aBarButtons.Add(new UIBarButtonItem(this.oBookmarkSwitch));
oIndexToolbar.SetItems (aBarButtons.ToArray (), false);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uisegmentedcontrol) is not very clear on this but it state that:

"You register **the** target-action methods for a segmented control using the
UIControlEventValueChanged constant as shown below." (emphasis mine)

Also discussions from [Apple](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/1521361?start=0&tstart=0) and [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1620972/uisegmentedcontrol-register-taps-on-selected-segment) forums seems to indicate that only the **ValueChange** event is supported - which would match the runtime behavior. I.e. there's no MonoTouch specific code for the UISegmentedControl events (e.g. to remove support for inherited events like **TouchUpInside**).

Comment: But ValueChanged doesn't fire either when clicking the control. See my example above. It is called once when the control's instance is created but never when touching it.

Comment: poupou, don't bother searching for an answer for now! It works if I do it in a separate project. So it seems to be a side effect of something else. I'll post if I find the issue. Sorry for bothering you.