# How to make UISegmentedControl's selected segment unselectable?

Tags: ios, uisegmentedcontrol

It is possible to set no selected segment in Storyboard when you create a UISegmentedControl by deselecting every segment's "Selected" attribute.

But at runtime, once you've selected one segment, it is not possible to deselect it without selecting another segment of the same segmentedControl. In fact, I would like to handle a "no selected segment" state (which is already the beginning state here). If the user tap the first segment, the selected segment would be the first. Then if the user tap it the first segment again, it would deselect it and there would be no selected segment.

I found how to deselect it programmatically using :

```
[menu setSelectedSegmentIndex:UISegmentedControlNoSegment]; // set it to -1 in fact
```

but I did not find a way / a place yet to handle this deselection operation...

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Try to `Ctrl`+drag your `UISegmentControl` into the your implemetation code area.

That should even you when the user select one of the buttons in the `UISegmentControl`.

Hope that help u.

Comment: The problem is that I receive an event only when the value has changed, which is not the case when you tap the already selected segment.

Comment: Try to add a tap event on top the selected area (wiered solution, but can works)

Comment: That would certainly work but this would be the first step to the dark side my dear. I'm looking for a more "proper" way to handle it.
Using TouchUpInside does not work since UISegmentedControl does not send this event.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1620972/uisegmentedcontrol-register-taps-on-selected-segment looks like what I'm looking for.