# Swift handle action on segmented control

Tags: ios, swift, uisegmentedcontrol

I have a HMSegmentedControl with 4 segments. When it is selected, it should pop up view. And when the pop up dismissed, and trying to click on same segment index it should again show the pop up. By using following does not have any action on click of same segment index after pop up dissmissed.

```
segmetedControl.addTarget(self, action: "segmentedControlValueChanged:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)
```

Comment: consider this instead http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1620972/uisegmentedcontrol-register-taps-on-selected-segment

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You set your target to fire just when the value change, so if you select the same segment the value will not change and the popover will not display, try to change the event to TouchUpInside, so it will be fired every time you touch inside the segment

```
segmentedControl.addTarget(self, action: #selector(segmentedControlValueChanged(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
```

Comment: I already tried this by using TouchUpInside event. But it is not working. No event happens while using it.

Comment: did you try .AllEvents as well?

Comment: Nice, glad I could help

Comment: I tried both `.TouchUpInside` and `.AllEvents` and they do not work. 
see this instead http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1620972/uisegmentedcontrol-register-taps-on-selected-segment. I don't know why the OP accepted this answer

Comment: `.valueChanged` Event will work for UISegmentControl.

Comment: `.allEvents` will be called more times, so that could be expensive

Comment: @ranjit.x.singh but if long press and select from dropdown, value changed is not called

Answer (score 63):

You can add the same target for multiple events.

So lets say your `segmentedControlValueChanged:` looks like this:

```
@objc func segmentedControlValueChanged(_ sender: UISegmentedControl) {
    if sender.selectedSegmentIndex == 0 {
        // value for first index selected here
    }
}
```

Then you can add targets for more than 1 events to call this function:

```
segmentedControl.addTarget(self, action: #selector(segmentedControlValueChanged(_:)), for: .valueChanged)
segmentedControl.addTarget(self, action: #selector(segmentedControlValueChanged(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
```

Now your function will get called when a value was changed and when the user releases his finger.

Comment: This does not seem to work with Xcode 14

Answer (score 20):

with sender, use the sender name sender when you want to access in the action:

```
segmentControl.addTarget(self, action: #selector(changeWebView(sender:)), for: .valueChanged)
```

or

```
addTarget(self, action: #selector(changeWebView), for: .valueChanged)
```

Answer (score 19):

Swift 5

// add viewController

```
@IBOutlet var segmentedControl: UISegmentedControl!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    segmentedControl.addTarget(self, action: #selector(CommentsViewController.indexChanged(_:)), for: .valueChanged)
}
```

// using change

```
@objc func indexChanged(_ sender: UISegmentedControl) {
    if segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 0 {
        print("Select 0")
    } else if segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 1 {
        print("Select 1")
    } else if segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 2 {
        print("Select 2")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
@IBAction func segmentedControlButtonClickAction(_ sender: UISegmentedControl) {
   if sender.selectedSegmentIndex == 0 {
      print("First Segment Select")
   }
   else { 
      print("Second Segment Select")
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Swift4 syntax :

```
segmentedControl.addTarget(self, action: "segmentedControlValueChanged:", for:.touchUpInside)
```

Answer (score 0):

Drag and drop create an action which is a value type.

[image]

```
@IBAction func actionSegment(_ sender: Any) {
    let segemnt = sender as! UISegmentedControl
    print(segemnt.selectedSegmentIndex)// 0 , 1

}
```