# Is there any way i can register a touch down for UISegmentedControl

Tags: ios, uisegmentedcontrol, uitouch

I have a segmented control,with 5 segments..I want some event to be fired when a touch down happens on any of the segment and i mean tap and hold,without lifting the finger.
And when the user lifts his finger,it should reset

I have tried using touchesBegan and touchesEnded but i don't get the current selectedIndex in touchesBegan,here's my code

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{

    long oldValue = self.selectedSegmentIndex;
    [super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
    if (oldValue == self.selectedSegmentIndex )
        [self sendActionsForControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
}

-(void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    NSLog(@"touchesEnded");
    NSLog(@"selectedIndex%lu",self.selectedSegmentIndex);
    [super touchesEnded:touches withEvent:event];
    self.selectedSegmentIndex = -1;
}
```

Is there any way to achieve a touch down event effect for a segmentedControl,or any other alternative?

Comment: In touchesBegan, the segment is not yet selected, so you can't get it.

Comment: @kientux Is there any way i can get the selected index before?? I want the event to be fired when its touch down

Comment: I think with UISegmentedControl only, there's nothing can do with touch down event, because segment get selected only when touch up. If you really want to do this, you can place a transparent button on each segment, and when button got touched down, call `setSelectedSegmentIndex:`. Then you have both touch down event and selected index.

Answer (score 0):

You can use touchDown: IBAction selector.

Comment: It doesn't work,i already tried,UISegmentedControl works with only valueChanged selector

Comment: Check this thread - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1620972/uisegmentedcontrol-register-taps-on-selected-segment

Answer (score 0):

You can try to override:

```
- (void) setSelectedSegmentIndex:(NSInteger)toValue
```

Answer (score 0):

Quite frankly, I do not think it is possible to do with `UISegmentedControl`. You do not get selected segment index until `touchesEnded:withEvent:` is called.

If you want to get in `touchesBegan:withEvent:`, my advise would be to write your own custom view that look like `UISegmentedControl` and gives you call back on `touchesBegan:withEvent:`.

As suggested by kientux above, adding transparent views or buttons on top of each segment in `UISegmentedControl` could be another potential solution to your problem but it would be very very tricky!

Good luck!